# Spelling Variances in different Traditions

Tags: english, vowels-nekudot, spelling-variants

Certain individuals in my acquaintance, within their respective communities, use the spelling "Matzo" for unleavened bread, while others opt for "Matzah." Similarly, there is variance in spelling for Jewish law, with some using "Halacha" and others "Halacho." I'm interested in exploring the reasons behind these distinctions and would appreciate any sources or references shedding light on this matter.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew

Comment: The O Vs A in matza, is because some people pronounce the Hebrew vowel kamatz as "uh", some as "oh" and others as "ah". So each person spelled it according to his own pronunciation (the same could be said about words that people spell with an s and others with a t, like bris/Brit, as well as "e" Vs "ei" or "ey" in some cases )

Comment: Worth noting that “halacho” seems to be internally inconsistent. You’re transliterating the same vowel (kamatz) twice, the first time using “a” and the second time using “o”. (I have the same issue when people write “Hatzolah”.)

Answer (score 0):

The linked discussion is discussing spelling, rather than pronunciation. While it is true that the
traditional way to pronounce it is Matzoh (mah-tzaw), there is an epidemic of sorts in the US of people pronouncing it Matzah (mah-tzah). This
stems from the way that American English enunciation works.
The correct way to pronounce the Komatz is as an open-mid-back-rounded vowel (click on this link for a recording https://www.wikiwand.com/en/File:PR-open-mid_back_rounded_vowel.ogg). This sound is produced by making an o-shape with the lips while vocalizing. This kind of enunciation is not  common in American English (it can be seen in words like “thought” in some parts of the US), and as such, Americans typically substitute the nearest common vowel. In European languages (such as German or French), this vowel is found more frequently, and thus nationals of these countries have an easier time differentiating the sounds. In American pronunciations, the vowel which is substituted is an open-mid-back-unrounded vowel (sound here: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/File:PR-open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel2.ogg). This is produced in the same part of the mouth as the previous pronunciation, but without rounding the lips into an O shape. In some communities, this has devolved even further, becoming a near-open central vowel (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/File:Near-open_central_unrounded_vowel.ogg).
When it comes to spelling, there are several factors in play. There is a debate about whether to use an A, an O, or (less commonly) a U, as the Komatz sound. The reason for this debate is that there is a general consensus that none of the aforementioned letters perfectly match the sound of [image]the Komatz. Another factor being considered is that each of these letters also represents another Neqqudoh (A for Passach, O for Cholam, U for Shuruk). I think the
reason that A is most commonly used is that the phonetic sound for Komatz is more similar to that of the Passach than it is to the Cholam or Shuruk, and using one of the others is therefore more likely to cause confusion. (A good example of where this can get confusing is the word Cholent/Chulent. Both are pronounced the same, but the latter one looks like it might say “choo-lent.”) Another factor to be considered is the culture one comes from. As is mentioned by the second reply in the Mi Yodeya forum, it is common for people to transliterate words according to how they pronounce them. The poster also brings up the use of T vs S in words like Brit/Bris, and this would likely go together with how one would transliterate the Komatz.
A third factor to consider is the conventions of the language being used to transliterate. In
Germanic languages (e.g. German, English etc.), a Komatz is generally transliterated with an A.
In German communities, the standard conventions of transliteration are very unusual, to say the least. Komatz is almost always an A, and a ssof (ת (is always transliterated with a T, even though it is never pronounced as such. You can still see this in many Yekkishe communities, such as Washington Heights.
I was recently exchanging emails with the Chazzan of the Yekke shul in Lakewood (he’s from
Washington Heights) about the spelling of a certain word, and he mentioned that he believes the correct niqud is a “pattach [sic].” However, when I was discussing the same matter with him in person a week later, he pronounced it as “passach.” A similar theme is seen with Bris/Brit and Shabbos/Sabbath (the latter one is pronounced “Shabbat” if read in German, and some people write it as such), to name a few.Interestingly, there is a movement now in Washington Heights and other Yekkishe communities to switch from using an A to using an O (I think this is wrong; more on this below). This highlights the cultural effect on the way people transliterate words; not necessarily how they are pronounced, but how it is widely accepted to spell them.
If you look at Ashkenazi siddurim printed in the US in recent times, you will come across words that have had their English transliteration standardized, such as:
• Mincha (or Minchah [the added H represents the ה at the end of the word in Hebrew])
• Aleinu
• Shabbos
• Shalosh Regalim
• Birkas HaMazzon (or HaMazon; the former accounts for the dagesh in the zayin, while the
latter does not)
• Asher Yatzar
• Chanukah
• Amidah
• Torah
• Avinu Malkeinu
• Mussaf
• Chazzan
• Shavuos
These words have mostly been accepted as being spelled like this. Many people (likely most) will have become accustomed to seeing them spelled as such and would likely be confused if they came across them spelled differently. For some people, the difference in spelling might even make the
word unintelligible. I’ve listed the same examples here, but changed all occurrences of Komatz to an O:
• Mincho (or Minchoh)
• Oleinu
• Shabbos
• Sholosh Regolim
• Birkas HaMozzon (or HaMozon)
• Asher Yotzar
• Chanukoh
• Amidoh
• Toroh
• Ovinu Malkeinu
• Mussof
• Chazzon
• Shovuos
Some of these examples look fine to me (e.g. Asher Yotzar, Amidoh, etc.), but others look
completely wrong (e.g. Toroh, Ovinu Malkeinu, Sholosh, etc.).
In the following image (taken of the Roth Machzor Shivchei Yeshurun), we can see some such
applications and the kind of problems that can arise from it.
[image]

On this page, we can see that the author used the accepted conventions for Amida and Pinchas, but used the alternate spelling for Chazzon and Yochonon (to mention a few). Each of these two examples has a problem that arises from using this spelling:
• Chazzon (חזן  (can be mistaken for Chazon (חזון] (as in Shabbas Chazon]. In Hebrew, a
Komatz is switched with a Passach at the end of the word if there is a link (סמיכות (between
it and the next word (e.g. חזן ראשונה  .(This is not the case with a Cholam (at least not when
discussing a Komatz Gadol, which this is).
• Yochonon appears at first glance to read יוחונון) enough said, I think).

You can see from my own spelling two lines ago that I don’t stick to one vowel or the other, but
rather I use them contextually. In the word “komatz,” there is a passach in the word next to the
komatz, so I use an O to separate them. In the next word “Gadol,” there a cholam and no passach, so I switch and use an A for the komatz. When there is both a cholam and a passach (e.g הושענא רבה  ,(I use an A, as it is not as confusing (as I mentioned previously) (e.g. Hosha’na Rabboh). I think this is the most objectively clear way to transliterate a komatz. However, if there is clearly
an accepted convention for how to write something (e.g. Amidah), I think it is more important to
follow the convention than to change it for logical reasons.
If you look in the Siddur Safah Yesharah, you can see this method applied to the instructions. I’ve attached an image with some examples underlined:

One notable place with I digress from the accepted convention is the word ,ברכו ,which I always
transliterate as Borachu, even though it is generally written as Barchu. The reason for this is that the komatz is a komatz gadol, which causes the Sh’va to be a Sh’va Noh (This is why Yekkes have a Chataf Passach instead of a Sh’va. The two are inherently the same Nekkudoh, but the Passach is used here to avoid people reading it as a Sh’va Nach [this is not actually the reason it is used
here, but I’m going to pretend that it is for the purpose of this monologue]).
The spelling “Barchu” seems to indicate both that the Komatz is a Komatz Koton (which
incidentally is traditionally pronounced how the Americans pronounce every Komatz), and also
that the ר has a Sh’va Nach. Both of these points are incorrect, and I’ve therefore strayed from the accepted convention to avoid these mistakes.

Comment: Re: chulent - some dialects of yiddish (eg Polish or Ukrainian) would definitely pronounce it choo-lent.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph, that's a little counterintuitive. Sefardim pronounce kamatz katan as "o" (very similar / identical to how they pronounce cholam) and kamatz gadol as "a". When you are particular to write Borachu - the "o" there would make me think it's a kamatz katan.